# How to parse POST parameters and values inside JQuery POST from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to parse POST parameters inside jQuery POST from outside something like:

```
var PARS = 'name: "Donald Duck", city: "Duckburg"';
$.post("demo_test_post.asp",{ PARS },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  }
);
```

Of course this doesn't work, I want to know why and how it can be done correctly.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without seeing the server side of things but i'm going out on a limb and i'm going to say that your 'PARS' variable should be a object instead of a string, and you can pass that directly into the post method as such:

```
var PARS = {name: 'Donald Duck', city: 'Duckburg'};
$.post('demo_test_post.asp', PARS, function(data, status) {
  alert('Data: ' + data + '\nStatus: ' + status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Holly cow! I'm an idiot!

it's simply **an object**, here is the solution:

```
var PARS = {name: "Donald Duck", city: "Duckburg"};   
$.post("demo_test_post.asp", PARS ,
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  }
);
```